# gpg-zip using secret key sign a zip

Tags: digital-signature, gnupg

I have the following problem.

I created a Key-Pair with Thunderbird (Engimail), then I exported the asc file, and importet it in the git bash to gpg.

Now I need to sign a zip.

Using the command:

```
gpg-zip --sign abc.txt def.txt
```

I get the message:

```
gpg: no default secret key: secret key not available
gpg: signing failed: secret key not available
```

No I've read that you can set the default key with:

```
gpg --default-key <keyid>
```

When I type this in the bash I get the message:

```
gpg: Go ahead and type your message ...
```

Now I can type and type nothing happens, when I press CTRL-D it says

```
 gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
 gpg: processing message failed: eof
```

I've also tried to set the default-key in the gpg.conf file, but it does not work.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use --default-key as part of a gpg command, e.g.

```
gpg --sign --default-key ABCD1234 file.txt
```

which will both run the command (in this example sign the file with key ABCD1234) and set gpg's default key.

Update:

Actually, on my box it looks like gpg-zip is ignoring gpg's default key, so probably need to go with @[Peter Harmann's](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/175190/peter-harmann) answer.

Answer (score 1):

U can try specifying the key with the [-u argument](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/gpg_002dzip.html). So you would use something like:

`gpg-zip -u 0xFFFFFFFF --sign abc.txt def.txt`

or

`gpg-zip --sign --gpg-args -u 0xFFFFFFFF abc.txt def.txt`